# Dynamically create methods in Controller (RAILS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, metaprogramming

I am trying to dynamically create methods for semi static pages. However, the code below does not seem to work.   I get a `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  pages = %w[ page1 page2 page3 ]

  pages.each do |page|          
    define_method(page) do |a|
      #do nothing
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Which line/method is that?

Comment: define_method(page) do |a|

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve with this? It likely has a simpler solution.

Comment: ArgumentError in PagesController#page1, wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: just trying to define the page methods dynamically.  e.g. def page1 end, def page2 end, etc etc.

Comment: That's __what__ you are doing. But what are you doing this __for__?

Comment: I think, these methods are for showing static pages. right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are saying that the method `:page1` (`:page2` and `:page3` too) have one parameter (`a`), but controller actions don't have parameters, they receive values from the params hash.

**EDIT**: Simply remove the `|a|` from your code:

```
define_method(page) do
  #do nothing
end
```

Answer (score 2):

block without arguments:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  pages = %w[ page1 page2 page3 ]

  pages.each do |page|          
    define_method(page) do
      #do nothing
    end
  end
end
```